# Interfaces - register class inheriting interface to create objects based on the class

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

How can I "register" a class which implements an interface to create objects based on the "registered" class? Let me explain what I want to do:

I an coding a request processor for my thread pooled server and I want the request processor can be "configured" on the server so I can choose which request processor the server should use for it's requests. Here is how I think it should have worked:

```
// yes I know the interface can't extend the abstract Thread class ...
// see in the Server class what I want to do with it
public interface RequestProcessor extends Thread {

public final Socker socket;

RequestProcessor(final Socket paramSocket) {
    socket = paramSocket;
}

// abstract so each request processor implementing this interface
// has to handle the request in his specific way
abstract void run();

}

public class RequestProcessorA implements RequestProcessor {

RequestProcessorA(final Socket paramSocket) {
    super(paramSocket);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // do something with the request
}

}

public class RequestProcessorB implements RequestProcessor {

RequestProcessorB(final Socket paramSocket) {
    super(paramSocket);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // do something different with the request
}

}
```

So having this as interface (or as abstract class to be able to extend the Thread class) I want to create a server and tell him to use wheater RequestProcessorA or RequestProcessorB like:

```
public class Server extends Thread {

private final RequestProcessor processor;
private final ServerSocker server;

Server(final int paramPort, final RequestProcessor paramProcessor) {
    processor = paramProcessor;
    server = new ServerSocket(paramPort);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        // how can I create a new RequestProcessorA object if "processor" is type of RequestProcessorA???
        // how can I create a new RequestProcessorB object if "processor" is type of RequestProcessorB???
        // how can I create a new CustomProcessor object if "processor" is type of CustomProcessor???
        RequestProcessor rp = ???;
        // add rp to the thread pool
    }
}

}
```

So how to design such requirements? I wan't to make this an extendable library so others can simply use the server and just have to code their own request processors by extendimg/implementing my interface/abstract class and simply "register" their own request processor?

I hope you guys understand what I mean. And sorry if this is a dup but I dont really know the technical terms for this :/

Comment: See `java.util.ServiceLoader.`

Comment: @EJP so this isn't a simple interface/abstract class question?

Comment: @Pali This is about _creation_ of instances, so it's more complicated than that.

Comment: @Pali No, it is an interface/abstract class/factory/registration question, and that is the answer that Java provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the [Abstract Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). Create one factory interface, and one implementation for each class you might want to produce:

```
public interface IRequestProcessorFactory {
    RequestProcessor create(Socket paramSocket);
}
```

and implement it like this:

```
public class RequestProcessorAFactory implements IRequestProcessorFactory {
    public RequestProcessor create(Socket paramSocket) {
        return new RequestProcessorA(paramSocket);
    }
}
```

and pass an instance of it to `Server`. Then, call

```
RequestProcessor rp = factory.create(socket);
```

to obtain what will either be a `RequestProcessorA` or `RequestProcessorB`, depending on which factory was passed.

Comment: Would you not consider this Factory method pattern rather than Abstract Factory ?

Comment: Working like a charm! Thank you very much random citizen!

Comment: Great!
@John: I believe that this is Abstract Factory, since we have multiple factories, one per class that we might want to produce. I don't think it matters that the parent type is an interface rather than an abstract class. Look at the class diagram in the Wikipedia article.